# Testing for return value from $q.when in Angular JS using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a factory as follows:

```
var myFactory = function ($q) {
    factory = {};

    factory.newObject = function() {
        return $q.when({ id: 0 }});
    };
};

angular.module('myModule').factory('myFactory', myFactory);
```

How can I use jasmine to test the newObject function and ensure id returned is 0?
Here's what I have so far:

```
describe("My Factory Test", function () {

    var testMyFactory;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (myFactory) {
        testMyFactory = myFactory;
    }));

    it('New Entity', function ($q) {
        testMyFactory.newObject().then(function(myObj) {
            expect(myObj.id).toBe(0); // does not work
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked:

```
describe("My Factory Test", function () {

  var testMyFactory, rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (myFactory, $rootScope) {
    testMyFactory = myFactory;
    rootScope = $rootScope;
  }));

  it('New Entity', function () {
    var testObj;
    testMyFactory.newObject().then(function(myObj) {
        testObj = myObj;
    });

    rootScope.$apply();
    expect(testObj.id).toBe(0);
  });
});
```